# Json Deserialize for hetero-type json Java

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

Apologies in advance, I'm a little new to JSON parsing and I m facing a problem in parsing JSON in Object in java.

```
{ result: {
      "City": {
        "Delhi": {
          "A-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 400001
          },
          "B-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 400002
          },
          "C-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 400003
          },
          .
          .
          .
        },
        "Mumbai": {
          "A-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 500001
          },
          "B-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 500002
          },
          "C-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 500003
          },
          .
          .
          .
        },
        "Bangalore": {
          "A-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 600001
          },
          "B-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 600002
          },
          "C-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 600003
          },
          "D-Hospital": {
            "pincode": 600004
          },
          .
          .
          .
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

Receiving Json is received from 3rd person hence can't the format.
How to create the class structure for such dynamic json and parse into Object ?

```
class City{
  private Map<String, Map<String,Hospital>> hours;
//Getter and Setter
}

class Hospital {
    private String pincode;
    //Getter and Setter
}
```

I want to form a Map of the City with Hospital(A-Hospital,B-Hospital,etc) as Object. Example: Map<String,Hospital> cityHospitalMapping. class Hospital { String HospitalName; Integer pincode; }

But How to write the Deserializer ?
Tried

```
JsonObject allcities = (JsonObject) json.get("result");
City cities = new Gson().fromJson(allcities,City.class);
```

But cities is not containing any data.

```
Result:
cities{pincode=null}
```

Comment: I want to form a Map of the City with Hospital(A-Hospital,B-Hospital,etc) as Object.
Example: Map<String,Hospital> cityHospitalMapping.
class Hospital {
  String HospitalName;
 Integer pincode;
}

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update with further details rather than posting in comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** because you added the `result` in your JSON. Your problem here - after edit - is that `City` you declared does not contain but it itself **IS** a `Map<String, Map<String,Hospital>>`.

First of all you need a "wrapper" class, say `Data`. That is because your JSON example has an object that contains `Response` that contains `City`.
**For `City`, there are no fixed field names so you need to deserialize it as a `Map`**.

**The same applies to values held in the map `City`**. Values in `City` are also type of `Map` let us call these values inner map. Because there is this one fixed field name `pincode` you can declare before mentioned values in this inner map as of type `Hospital`, leading to a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Data {
    @Getter @Setter
    public class Result {
        private Map<String, Map<String, Hospital>> City;
        @Getter @Setter
        public class Hospital {
            private String pincode;
        }
    }
    private Result result;
}
```

Now if you deserialize with Gson using this above class you can use it like:

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(JSON, Data.class);
Map<String, Map<String, Hospital>> city = data.getResult().getCity();
```

and obtain `400002`.

You could implement some more or less complex custom deserializer but maybe it is more easy to deserialize JSON as it is and after tath do some mappings to other types of classes if needed.